# Sports "which/that" I have to run vs sports "where" I have to run

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I'm Italian and I don't know what the best choice is.

1. I don't like sports **which/that** I have to run.
2. I don't like sports **where** I have to run.

What's the right relative?

Comment: A title like "help me please" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 1):

"Where" is fine, although informal.  "In which I have to run" is more formal, but the "in" is essential.  "That" is a no-go.

"Where" may be a little controversial, but here's what [Collins English Dictionary says](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/where?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic):

> It was formerly considered incorrect to use where as a substitute for in which after a noun which did not refer to a place or position, but this use has now become acceptable: we now have a situation where/in which no further action is needed

Comment: Though, as I indicated above, I personally would not use "where" in a case like this, I don't consider it wrong when others do so. Also, I answered this question only to provide a few more possibilities than you have, but clearly you posted your correct answer prior to mine, so I have up-voted you.

Comment: "Where" is fine and perfectly natural.

Comment: And, so? Does that mean I have to use it myself?

Comment: @surlawda I don't have any objection to that; I just saw your remarks and thought it would be helpful to include some commentary from someone authoritative about this usage.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I was wondering about @BillJ--you gave a source, I said I'm fine with that, and he just seemed to repeat your point without adding anything, so I am wondering if his comment has something in it that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use neither. The first sentence makes it sound as if you like only those sports that you are not in charge of (*run* meaning "to control, manage, or direct"), and the second fails, IMO, because *where* generally refers to place or location. Granted, many people speaking loosely do use *where* as you have, but, personally, I would say:

> I don't like sports *in* which I have to run.

or

> I don't like sports that make me run

or

> I don't like sports that require running.

Comment: Good point about the possible confusion with the word "run".